# Is it possible to enable iCloud without user intervention (ie programmatically)?

Tags: icloud, ios7.1

I'm getting ready to add Ensenbles to my iPad app, and trying to figure out how much of a problem it's going to be if the device is not iCloud enabled, and then figure out how to get the device enabled, without user intervention (if that's at all possible).

Is this possible? (to enable iCloud without user intervention)

Comment: As Tom says, you can't programmatically activate iCloud. But you can detect if the user is logged in with the Documents & Data setting on, by using the NSFileManager ubiquityIdentityToken property. If they don't login, they can't sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not at all. If the user doesn't enable iCloud, you don't get to override their decision. You can ask them to enable iCloud, but you can't do anything about it in your app.